# Using a variable within a string

Tags: variable, string

I'm stuck on a problem. I am a biologist who uses linux for automation so I don't have the best programming background and would appreciate your help.

I have a large text file, containing several thousand lines of text, for example :

```
1. ATOM   1698  NE2AGLN A 400      14.237 -14.941 -28.964  0.50 19.10    -0.370 N 
2. ATOM   1699  HE2A1GLN A 400      15.059 -14.399 -28.698  1.00  0.00     0.159 HD
3. ATOM   1700  HE2A2GLN A 400      13.869 -15.668 -28.351  1.00  0.00     0.159 HD
4. ATOM   1701  NE2BGLN A 400      11.754 -15.026 -32.239  0.50 15.67    -0.370 N 
5. ATOM   1702  HE2B1GLN A 400      11.970 -15.937 -31.835  1.00  0.00     0.159 HD
6. ATOM   1703  HE2B2GLN A 400      11.794 -14.906 -33.251  1.00  0.00     0.159 HD
7. ATOM   1704  N   ASP A 401      10.553 -18.216 -28.161  1.00 15.63    -0.231 NA
8. ATOM   1705  CA AASP A 401      10.830 -19.591 -27.761  0.50 16.06     0.160 C
```

I need to modify some lines of this file in order to use it, by deleting one of the spaces for lines which do not line up with the others. In my listed code, lines 2,3,5, and 6 contain too many characters so I need to delete a space. I am looking to delete a single space between column 2 and 3 when needed (between 1702 and HE2B1GLN for example.

I have written a code which uses a series of sed commands to find rows with these issues and replace them with the same string, minus 1 space. An example would be:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
echo $i

    sed "s/  HE2B$iGLN/ HE2B$iGLN/g" NEW2.pdbqt>NEW3.pdbqt

done
```

The problem is that while this does repair the bad lines, it leaves out the columns which end in "GLN." This is a problem because I need to create a loop of some kind to change 1 number in the middle of the string, but I need both sides of the string to remain a part of the sed command.

Hopefully that's clear enough, this is my first programming post.

Does anyone know the proper syntax/workaround for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact contents of the file?  As written, multiple spaces are rendered as one space.  And if your file doesn't contain line numbers, please don't include them here.  Just paste your file contents between two lines that contain 3 backticks (\`\`\`)

Comment: The immediate problem is that when the shell sees `HE2B$iGLN/`, it tries to expand a variable named `iGLN` (which doesn't exist, so it expands to `HE2B/`). You could fix this by using `HE2B${i}GLN/` (the braces make it explicit where the variable name ends), but really there are better ways to solve the larger problem. See Bill Jetzer's answer for some possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, you could just run one sed statement that uses a regex matching any number of numeric characters:

```bsh
sed 's/  *\( HE2B[0-9][0-9]*GLN\)/\1/g;' NEW2.pdbqt > NEW3.pdbqt
```

Is it only the `HE2B` lines that have this problem, or is it all of them? And just the 3rd field in the file, or are there other instances of multiple spaces?  You could use this to squash all instances of multiple spaces on all lines so that there will only ever be one space in a row:

```bsh
sed 's/   */ /g;' NEW2.pdbqt > NEW3.pdbqt
```

And if you have problems with leading and/or trailing spaces, you could trim those off as well:

```bsh
sed 's/^  *//; s/  *$//; s/   */ /g;' NEW2.pdbqt > NEW3.pdbqt
```

Running the above on this file (where I'm using "!" to denote trailing spaces):

```
   ATOM    1698 NE2AGLN A 400 14.237 -14.941 -28.964 0.50 19.10 -0.370 N
ATOM 1699 HE2A1GLN A 400 15.059 -14.399 -28.698 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1700    HE2A2GLN A 400 13.869 -15.668 -28.351      1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1701 NE2BGLN A 400 11.754 -15.026 -32.239 0.50 15.67 -0.370 N
ATOM 1702  HE2B1GLN A 400 11.970 -15.937 -31.835 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD!!
ATOM 1703       HE2B2GLN A 400 11.794 -14.906 -33.251 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
          ATOM 1704 N ASP A 401 10.553 -18.216 -28.161 1.00 15.63 -0.231 NA!!!!
ATOM 1705 CA AASP A 401 10.830 -19.591 -27.761 0.50 16.06 0.160 C
```

produces this:

```
ATOM 1698 NE2AGLN A 400 14.237 -14.941 -28.964 0.50 19.10 -0.370 N
ATOM 1699 HE2A1GLN A 400 15.059 -14.399 -28.698 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1700 HE2A2GLN A 400 13.869 -15.668 -28.351 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1701 NE2BGLN A 400 11.754 -15.026 -32.239 0.50 15.67 -0.370 N
ATOM 1702 HE2B1GLN A 400 11.970 -15.937 -31.835 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1703 HE2B2GLN A 400 11.794 -14.906 -33.251 1.00 0.00 0.159 HD
ATOM 1704 N ASP A 401 10.553 -18.216 -28.161 1.00 15.63 -0.231 NA
ATOM 1705 CA AASP A 401 10.830 -19.591 -27.761 0.50 16.06 0.160 C
```

Comment: The problem is only with specific rows, and only in the third column. The HE2B rows are one type that have it.

I like using the brackets instead of the loop, but this code deletes both spaces so also does not work. I tried using

    sed "s/  HE2A[0-9]GLN/ HE2A[0-9]GLN/g" NEW3.pdbqt>NEW4.pdbqt

And this did delete the 1 space, however it also changed all of my HE2A rows to HE2A[0-9]GLN. Is there a way to fix that?